# Private RDS in VPC, connect from EC2 in different VPC and region

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, rds, vpc-peering

I want to connect from a EC2 in US VPC to a private RDS in a EU VPC.  The AWS docs don't seem to mention this scenario - does anyone know if it's possible?

Thanks,

Comment: I had a similar issue, AWS suggests a VPC Peering connection. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.Scenarios.html

Answer (score 0):

AWS does not have an integrated, managed solution to cross-region VPC connectivity.

The "AWS Answers" document [Multiple Region Multi-VPC Connectivity](https://aws.amazon.com/answers/networking/aws-multiple-region-multi-vpc-connectivity/) explains some of the options currently available.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HAProxy to expose your SQL RDS to a remove client via the open Internet. You'll want to secure this!

Alternatively you can set up a VPN connection so you can route between the two VPCs.